# Ajax request in for loop and order of indices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem concerning the execution of ajax requests in a for loop. I already searched the web for it and found some solutions which I already implemented to avoid running the request synchronously. Unfortunately these solutions don't provide information how to ensure, that the success block gets called in the correct order aswell.

This is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        (function(index) {
        var path = array[index].split(";")[1];
        var selectedRevision = array[index].split(";")[0];

        $.ajax({
          url: 'svntojson.jsp?revHistoryForPath=' + path,
          dataType:'text',
          success:function(data){
              console.log(index);
              var $li = $("<li/>").text(path).addClass("ui-corner-all")
                  .prepend("<div class='handle'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s'></span></div>")
                  .append('<button class="delete"></button>')
                  .append('<select class="revHistoryOptions" style="float:right;margin-right:5px;">' + data.trim() + '</select>');

              $("#list").append($li);
              $("#list").sortable('refresh');
              $('.revHistoryOptions').eq(index).children('option[value=' + selectedRevision + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');

          }
        });
    })(i);
    }
```

However the order of indices can change because the one ajax request succeeds earlier. This wouldn't be a problem but I am appending some list elements in the success block and I need the exact order.

So my question is how to ensure that the success block of my ajax request will be called in the order of the for loop indices from 0 to n-1.

Comment: This is a wrong design. Why cant you simply use one ajax request and post the array itself to server. On the server, process each element and prepare the array of response. Send the response array to success callback and loop through it and add elements accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing the ajax call inside the loop. Do the required processing server side as @Vijay mentioned. In absolute case you can use `async: false` in your ajax to make it blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **WRONG DESIGN** : If you want a complete synchronized behavior and not involving any user interaction between iterations, you can avoid
>   looping and use single ajax request.

You can use a single ajax when you want it completely synchronized:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'svntojson.jsp?inputArray=' + array,
     dataType: 'json',//Note I changed this to json to receive the array on outputs
     success: function (data) {
         var resArray = data;
         for (var index = 0; index < resArray.length; index++) {
             var res = resArray[index];
             var $li = $("<li/>").text(res.path).addClass("ui-corner-all")
                 .prepend("<div class='handle'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s'></span></div>")
                 .append('<button class="delete"></button>')
                 .append('<select class="revHistoryOptions" style="float:right;margin-right:5px;">' + res.data + '</select>');

             $("#list").append($li);
             $("#list").sortable('refresh');
             $('.revHistoryOptions').eq(index).children('option[value=' + res.selectedRevision + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
         }
     }
 });
```

on the server:

process the input array and generate output for each element of array. (Psuedocode as following):

```
var resArray = new Array(inputArr.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
        var res = new res();
        res.path = inputArr[i].split(";")[1];
        res.selectedRevision = inputArr[i].split(";")[0];
        resArray.push(res);
    }
    return resArray;
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I think `res.data.trim()` would be undefined in your solution I definetly know now how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Just coming back to report that I got it working. I had to do some more stuff on server side to exactly get what I want but now it is working with just one request which runs without async:false.